# What might "serpent" on 19th century Australian gravestone indicate or suggest?

Tags: south-australia, grave-marker

This is not a great photo but it comes from the gravestone of my great-great-great-granfather James Smyth Stacy, a Boot and Shoe Maker, who was buried in Adelaide (South Australia) in 1864.

A symbol that I have interpreted as perhaps being a serpent is featured prominently, and I am wondering whether this indicates that he was a member of a particular lodge or whether it might have some other known significance?

[image]

To give a bit more context, this is the whole gravestone that has below the "snake/ribbon" inscriptions for him, his wife, one of his sons and one of his daughters.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks more like a ribbon with words on it than a snake. The circle surrounding,  is vaguely like a Celtic knot, so the ribbon could be a snake/serpent after all as the bottom of the ribbon looks like a head with an eye. Have a look at this [link](http://www.ehow.com/about_6327093_meaning-celtic-snake_.html)

[ I agree with the words Transcribed by  @ColeValleyGirl ]

**Carried**

**to the**

**Almighty**

**Lord**

[image: enhanced]

Comment: Thanks for enhancing this and I think you are right about the letters, and maybe it is a ribbon rather than a snake!  You are doing better at picking out the letters than I am but based on what you got I am wondering whether it is a religious message something like "Ferried to the Almighty Lord" (which could almost fit what you made out).

Comment: @PolyGeo, Carried to the Almighty Lord.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Are you both thinking it is more just decorative (with a religious message) rather than indicating a particular religion, lodge, occupation, etc?

Comment: @PolyGeo, I think it's a ribbon with a religious message. Do you have access to photographs of other gravestones of the same period in the same graveyard? That might help.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Good idea! I live interstate so will not get a chance to revisit and look to see if the symbol crops up elsewhere (where it may be more readable) but South Australia is lucky to have [**Torie's South Australian Grave Photos**](http://toriesgravephotos.weebly.com/) and I have just left a link to this Question and discussion on her Facebook page to see if someone there knows it.

Comment: @PolyGeo, FWIW wikipedia (without any citations) and various other places on the net (also without supporting info) say that a "Snake in a circle" on a gravestone means Everlasting life in Heaven.

Comment: The word from Torie's Facebook page is that she has not seen it before so I am going to conclude that it is just some sort of elaborate "snake in circle" adornment - and award the points to @Sam888 for his deciphering effort!